# xsl and XML transform producing duplicate records

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

I am getting duplicate records with the following xml and xsl file. I only want to transform 1 set of the list items. Try not removing anything from the xsl part (just add to it), if possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
  <listitems name="Select..." CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Item A" CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Item B" CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Select..." CtrId="Id4"/>
  <listitems name="Item A" CtrId="Id4"/>
  <listitems name="Item B" CtrId="Id4"/>  
  <listitems name="Select..." CtrId="Id6"/>
  <listitems name="Item C" CtrId="Id6"/>
  <listitems name="Item D" CtrId="Id6"/>  
</data>
```

```
  <xsl:template match="data/listitems">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Result (Incorrect behavior; Duplicate)
Select... Item A Item B Select... Item A Item B

Desired behavior (Only get 1 set)
Select... Item A Item B

Comment: I'd be inclined to suggest that your XML is poorly designed. I don't know if you have any control over it, but if you do, I'd recommend putting a `<Ctr Id="Id2">` element in as a child of `<data>`, and putting `<listitems name="Select...">` within that, etc. Usually anything which belongs in a group should be contained within an element representing that group. Any XSLT that operates on a group like this would be a LOT easier.

Comment: Is there a to grab the first set of CtrlIds that are the same?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good example- that would be trivial with the design I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple way of doing this:

```
<xsl:param name="useId" select="/data/listitems[1]/@CtrId" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Untitled</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="data/listitems[@CtrId = $useId]"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listitems">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ' ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Your existing template will actually put in an `html` element for every `listitems` element- it seems fairly likely that you probably only want the one.

The `<xsl:param>` declaration at the top picks the first CtrId in the file, and uses that. You can change that to a literal value with `select="'Id2'"` (note the single quotes inside the double quotes), or you can pass a parameter into the stylesheet with the ID you want to pick out.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "*[starts-with(@name,'Select')][1]"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name,'Select')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
    "(.|following-sibling::*
        [generate-id(following-sibling::*
                     [@name[starts-with(.,'Select')]][1]
                     )
        =
         generate-id(current()/following-sibling::*
                               [@name[starts-with(.,'Select')]][1])
        ]
     )/@name
    "/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@name" mode="inGroup">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
  <listitems name="Select..." CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Item A" CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Item B" CtrId="Id2"/>
  <listitems name="Select..." CtrId="Id4"/>
  <listitems name="Item A" CtrId="Id4"/>
  <listitems name="Item B" CtrId="Id4"/>
</data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <title>Untitled</title>
   </head>
   <body>Select... Item A Item B </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...I'm pretty to new to XSL. Can you offer any insights to a newbie? For example, Some of the symbols like .|following-sibling::* and generate-id and mode="inGroup"?

Comment: @rod: These are called "XPath expressions". Most of the XSLT instructions operate on XPath expressions that select particular node-sets. A single answer cannot provide all important information on the subject of XPath and XSLT. Please, read a good XPath and XSLT book to get introduced in XSLT. You can find some good resources listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305